# Should the [identify-this] tag be added to the other "identify" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Apparently someone created the tag https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this. Their question will likely be closed and deleted ASAP, but this tag will probably be available for the next day or so before it gets hovered up.

Perhaps this "workaround" should be added to the other "identify" tags to avoid it being recreated in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would agree with Paulie_D's answer that pragmatically there's not much of a need to add all kinds of hypothetical identification tags people could possibly come up with to the error blacklist. We have the tags that are still on the site on existing questions and I'd think that's enough.

There's only so much you can do to prevent people from asking questions they shouldn't ask or creating useless tags. In fact, when you type `identify-this` into the tag edit box (or even just `iden`), the first thing that pops up is the existing identification tags, complete with their loud warnings not to ask your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a nice idea but nothing us "user moderators" can't manage individually.

Firstly, we can edit the question to remove these new tags and once the question is roomba'd the tags will be deleted automatically in a day or so.

This user created several tags to add to this question and I have removed all of them and just left a single current, valid tag (as the question must have at least one).